# Working with Third party yummly api in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I've searched all over the web for decent explanations of how to do what I want to do, but cannot find any.

What I want to do is have the user be able to search through the yummly api and return some results back...

Here is some code.

index.html.erb

```
<% @results.each do |r| %>
  <%= r.name %>
  <% end %>
```

home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  @results = Yummly.search('Onion')
  @recipe = @results.map(&:to_s)
  end
end
```

I've installed the Yummly gem which allows me to call `Yummly.search` 
How can I allow the user to search for the term instead of hard coding it? It returns just fine hard coded but I cannot figure out how to allow the user to search.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you would have a form that allows the user to enter a search term, and then pass that term to the Yummly API.

Something like (substitute your own route name):

```
<%= form_tag({controller: 'home', action: 'index'}, {method: :get}) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'search' %>
<% end %>
```

And in your controller:

```
Yummly.search(params[:search])
```

Comment: I guess this is where I'm getting hung up a little bit. I dont' exactly know what route name to use. Say I've just generated a home_controller , what exactly would my route be?

Comment: it is whatever you defined it as in your `routes.rb` file. In this case if its your Home#index action going to process the form, you can leave it as I put it.

Comment: I'm trying, i really am. Thanks for being patient with me. <code> = form_tag {controller: 'home', action: 'index'} do
  = text_field_tag 'search'</code> Something like this? Because I'm returning errors. I'm just trying to figure out what I'm missing and why I can't seem to grasp this.

Comment: if you're using ERB, you'll need to wrap <% %> tags around things, eg. `<%= form_tag do %>`. It might be easier if you jump back on IRC and we can continue the discussion.